# grep device name and look for next value :

Tags: sed, grep, awk

I have this output from a find command:

```
abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23
```

where abc,def and geh are device names and could be of any length and others are IP address belong to devices. Like`abc,10.11.13.14` for device `abc`. IP shall be next to comma delimiter.

How can I use sed, grep or awk to print the associated IP when I grep for a device name? In short I want the IP to be displayed next to device name.

Answer (score 4):

I am more comfortable with awk, so I would like to present two solutions in awk.

#### Solution 1

```
$ echo abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23 | awk -F, '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) if ($i == "def") print $(i+1)}'
1.2.3.4
```

In this case, I am looking for a machine name "def", if found, print the next column.

#### Solution 2

```
$ echo abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23 | tr , \\n | awk '/def/ {getline;print}'
1.2.3.4
```

In this solution, I use the `tr` command to convert commas to new line, search for "def" and print the line that follows. I hope these solutions work for you.

Comment: Thanks you so much Mr Hai Vu for your kind assitance both the solution worked in my case....

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have GNU grep with Perl-compatible regular expressions:

```
device="def"
grep -oP '(?<=\b'"$device"',).*?(?=,|$)'
```

Which means: find the content between "def," on one side and "a comma or end-of-line" on the other

EDIT: added a word boundary to the RE to find the given device more precisely.

Comment: What if there's both a `def` and `xdef` device?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `(?:(?<=,def,)|(?<=^def,))`

Comment: There is a simpler RE for the grep...    `grep -oP "$device"',\K[^,]+'`

Comment: to handle def and xdef case...  save output in a variable  `output=$(....)`  then use  `ip= $( grep -oP ",$device"',\K[^,]+' <<< ",$output" )`

Answer (score 1):

Using grep(GNU) and cut:

```
$ echo abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23 | grep -o 'abc,[^,]*'  | cut -d, -f2
10.11.13.14
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Guru but its showing for a .... What is the significance of a ?

Comment: ohh..i have this habit of using filenames like a, b , etc..its just the file name..removing it....

Comment: You command has a double quote `"` that should not be there.

Comment: the problems of editing at the last minute :) thanks Hai Vu.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any command but shell builtins:

```
string='abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23'
dev=def

s=,$string,
case $s in
  (*,"$dev",*) ip=${s#*",$dev,"}; ip=${ip%%,*};;
  (*) ip=unknown
esac

printf '%s\n' "$ip"
```

With zsh, it's easy to map that string to an associative array:

```
string='abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23'
typeset -A ip
ip=(${(s:,:)string})
print -r -- $ip[def]
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute every  IP-address `[0-9\.]\{7,15\}` using sed. An IP address consists of numbers and dots, varying from 7 to 15 positions.

Replace every IP-address with itself followed by a newline `\n`, which basically means that every device,IP-combination will have its own line.

```
echo "abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23" | sed 's/\([0-9\.]\{7,15\}\),/\1\n/g' 
abc,10.11.13.14
def,1.2.3.4
geh,6.7.54.23


echo "abc,10.11.13.14,def,1.2.3.4,geh,6.7.54.23" | sed 's/\([0-9\.]\{7,15\}\),/\1\n/g'  | grep def
def,1.2.3.4
```